# React Socket IO is not connected to heroku server

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

I'm trying to get the server or port of heroku;this works fine on the localhost, but the socket.io feature doesn't work on heroku.

this is the error i get on heroku.

> websocket.js:120 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
>   Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   p.doOpen @ websocket.js:120

**App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const  app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log(socket.id);

    socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', (data)=>{
        io.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', data);

    })


});

http.listen(PORT,function(){
  console.log('listening on port %s',PORT);
});
```

**Chat.js**

```
// this has to be something other than localhost, it needs to work vice versa.

this.socket = socketIOClient('localhost:5000');

this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', function(data){
    addMessage(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardcoded workaround

**app.js**

```
  this.socket = socketIOClient.connect(HEROKU_PATH_HERE, {secure: true});

   if(!this.socket){
        this.socket = socketIOClient('localhost:5000');
   }
```